# How to Kill Ebony Warrior as a Mage

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have a mage with archmage's robes and all except ice master-level destruction spells, and still failed to kill him quite a few times already, my lightning storm just can't kill him before I get killed and fire storm deals such a pitiful amount of damage against him... Any adive? Maybe I should try other forms of magic such as conjuration? Or should I return once I have blizzard?

Comment: The Ebony warrior is a tank. Even melee builds have issue with him.

Comment: Tough guy, you could try conjuration, maybe with a scroll or something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main thing is to keep attention away from yourself. You want to use items to take the brunt of the hits, and you to spam him with your magic. Some good tips are as follows:

- Take along a melee follower. That way, you can prolong yourself for a little while. A really good one to take with you would be an essential follower (such as [Mjoll the Lioness](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Mjoll_the_Lioness)), since they can just keep getting back up and helping out.
- [Summon Karstagg](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Summon_Karstaag) will also help in that regard. He's a really
  powerful ally, and does help out a lot against him, but he has to be
  used sparingly (with only 3 uses of the spell available).

There are also some nice perks and spells that can help out as well:

- [Dragon Aspect](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Aspect) then [Dragonhide](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragonhide) are really handy shouts to
  have, as they will beef up your damage, and your resistances against
  him (I say then because they do not stack).
- If you have the vampire lord ability, I would recommend using that as
  well. This will give you some extra damage against him.
- If you want to be mean about it, if you've done destruction magic (which it sounds like you have), you could just keep using [impact](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Impact), getting your hits in (with you and your partners), then impact him when he gets out of it. Rinse and repeat.

Your lighting storm and fire storm should be ok against him. He just has that much health. Although, getting a few conjuration spells would certainly not hurt, as they can take away some of the attention from you and move it onto them (buying you some time to get some hits in).I believe his magic resistance is Slightly higher than his physical, so if its possible to use archery, I would recommend that as well. If not, the magic should be good enough.

Comment: Currently my best conjuration spell is just the dremora lord... is he enough to take on the ebony warrior?

Comment: Yea he should be good enough. Or, maybe pair him with something else like the summon karstagg or the follower. The more the merrier.

Comment: For followers I have J'zargo and Illia with Lydia (old one that), most are mages with ranged attacks... (except Lydia, but she can't do much against ebony warrior. ..)

Comment: If possible, you should try to get Mijol, Derkeethus, Serana, Cicero, or a Dark Brotherhood initiate, as they are the non-essentials. If not, I'd say use Lydia

Comment: So... I should go and do Dark Brotherhood questline?

Comment: They'd help. Mainly just for the followers after. Not a necessity, but certainly welcome. If you don't want to take that long, just grab Mijol from completing this quest: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Retrieve_Grimsever. She's like a Lydia, but essential, so she can't die

Comment: I easily defeated ebony warrior as a mage with the mentioned Impact perk. Even dragons fell with ease as it's such an OP perk.

Answer (score 1):

Dual casting destruction spell should stagger him, giving you time to increase the distance and increase the damage.

Alternatively, since the fight takes place on a cliff, you can shout him down. It won't kill him, but will help.

Source for these and other tactics : http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:The_Ebony_Warrior

Additional source about his strengths and weaknesses:

http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615803-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/65646888

Additionally the Slow Time shout will allow you to reposition, and he doesn't seem to be immune to slows, so you can try slowing him if he gets too close

Comment: Since I didn't invest much in health... two hits from hin can easily kill me... so in the end he just kills me before I manage to deal enough damage to him.

Comment: I understand, that's why both tactics are about stopping him, by either staggering him with the dual cast or pushing him down the cliff.
I'll ad another option to the answer in a moment

Comment: Vampires have easier time against him... but I suppose I'll try again with lightning storm/firebolt... Impact perk should work against him right?

Comment: Yes, it does work against him! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have a level 83 pure caster. No armor. No weapons. Ebony Jerk was really ticking me off, but I figured out how to finally beat him.
Prep:
Alteration & Restoration 100%, minimum. You need Dragonhide and Guardian Circle.
Spell absorption as high as you can get it.
Impact perk for two-handed spellcasting.

Tactics:
Get close to the Ebony Bozo, but just outside his aggro range. Do NOT try and range fight him- he paralyzes you almost every shot with that !@#$% bow of his.
Right outside his aggro radius, summon your Guardian Circle and get the Magicka Supercharger running. (Note: if you've never used this, it is a complete game-changer.)
Two-hand cast Incinerate at him before he has his shield up, and DO NOT LET UP! You need to keep him from arming that !@$%#@! Shield of Fire Supression he has. his lowest elemental resistance is to fire with no shield equipped- his other elemental resists are on his other gear he's wearing.

You're done. The Ebony Flatulence is done. And you're welcome. ;)

Bare-handed and cloth-wearing FTW!